# Codemirror - Get editor lines number

Tags: line, codemirror

I'm trying to get the number of lines in the codemirror editor to check if the editor contains more or less rows then some minutes befor. Is there any method or function in codemirror to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the function

```
var lines = editor.lineCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use: `editor.doc.size`